# How to change the marker line width in Plotly 3D scatter plot?

Tags: python, plotly-python

I am plotting x/y/z data using Plotly with Python and whatever I do, I cannot make the marker lines thicker. I followed the "manual" but they do it for 2D plots, which works for me, but I can't get it to work on the 3D version.

I create the plot:

```
fig = px.scatter_3d(df, x='xvalues', y='yvalues', z='zvalues')
```

I change the markers

```
fig.update_traces(marker=dict(
        color='lightblue',
        size=10,
        line=dict(color='purple',
                  width=3
        )))
```

colors and everything work, but there's either no line if I set the width to 0 or there is a line for every other value but it seems to be 1 px wide.

I also tried

```
fig.data[0].marker.line.width=3
```

which shows the exact same behavior. Line is gone when set to 0, line is 1 px wide when set to any other value.

Is there a way to fix this? Sadly the documentation isn't very good.

Answer (score 0):

Line dict should not be inside marker. Try this:

```
fig.update_traces(
    marker=dict(
        color='lightblue',
        size=10),
    line=dict(
        color='purple',
        width=3
    )
)
```

What I mean, you havn't set your brackets correctly

Comment: That way I get no marker borders at all. My method obviously does something since setting it to 0 disables it and color works too. I copied it from here https://plotly.com/python/marker-style/

Comment: I used the „3D Line Plot of Brownian Motion“ example from https://plotly.com/python/3d-line-plots/ to recreate your behaviour/example. Maybe the link helps. Sorry, I have no time to rewrite my code fully.

Comment: Oh I see. I am not talking about normal lines. I am interested in the border lines around markers. In my link the round markers have a dark border. I'm trying to make that one thicker.

Comment: Oh, that is too bad. 
I looked into the Object and also changed any width, I found there. Nothing changes.